# Can I use a ternary operator with angularjs outside of the class attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interpolation

I'm looping through a json object with AngularJS, and having trouble dealing with nulls.

I'm new to Angular.

```
<a href="#" data-mycustom="{{product.related}}">...</a>
```

In the event of related being null:

```
{
    "related":null
}
```

I want to put a "-1" in its place:

```
<a href="#" data-mycustom="-1">...</a>
```

Tried ternary operator but it isn't evaluating... it's just displaying it as plain text.

Comment: Make sure your angular is the latest version. The ternary operator is a fairly new addition.

Comment: Well I'm stumped. There are several alternative syntaxes, like `{true: a, false: b}[condition]`, which I've tried and seem to work when ternary doesn't. You'd use that like any other angular statement.

Comment: Oh.. my.. gosh. I figured out what I was doing wrong. Tenary works fine, if I put it all inside the curly brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you could use `ng-attr` to add custom attribute after evaluation of `{{}}` interpolation directive

**Markup**

```
<a href="#" ng-attr-data-mycustom="{{product.related || '-1' }}">...</a>
```

Comment: I actually figured out what I was doing wrong, and boy do I feel dumb... However, this method is cleaner/shorter, so thank you. Will accept as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, this is the answer the OP's original question ("how do you use a ternary in a directive"):

Add `{{}}` around the *entire* ternary statement, not just the variable. For example, this

```
<a href="#" data-mycustom="{{product.related}} ? product.related : '-1'">...</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="#" data-mycustom="{{product.related ? product.related : '-1'}}">...</a>
```

Otherwise, Angular won't parse it -- you'll get the value of `product.related`, followed by the literal text `? product.related : '-1'`.

Comment: I actually had the brackets around the just {{product.related}} instead of the whole tenary, so I was just half stupid :)

Comment: @user1447679 There! Fixed.

Comment: While the other answers are helpful, I think this answer should really be marked as the correct answer since it specifically talks about the ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

use or operator. this code will help :

```
<a href="#" data-mycustom="{{product.related || -1}}">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
<a href="#" ng-attr-data-mycustom="{{product.related || '-1' }}">...</a>
```

It is something like "try to use product.related if it exists. if it doesnt, use -1 insted"